# Securing access to plugin URL with spring security

Tags: security, grails, plugins

I want to install JavaMelody grails plugin, although that is only possible if I can secure access to it. There are a lot of people having this problem, the only applicable solution I found was using interceptUrlMap but that does not work either. This is what I have in my Config.groovy

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.auth.User'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.auth.UserRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName='username'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.auth.Role'
// grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "Annotation"

grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'InterceptUrlMap'
ograils.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap  = [
    '/monitoring': ['ROLE_ADMIN','IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']
]
```

The application is using annotation for security, although I disabled only to test if thats whats causing the problem, but without success.

What other options do I have for securing a URL? It has to be something that can be controlled from the application, and not any setting that is not contained in the grails application package.

Answer (score 0):

It appears it is working if I use the following:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
 '/monitoring/**': ['ROLE_ADMIN']
]
```